# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'u => (Guid?)u == EntityShaperExpression:

Tags: .net-6.0

```
var projects = _projectRepo.FindAll(x => listProjectIds.Any(u => u == x.Id)).ToList();
// .FindAll() return IQueryable<T>
// listProjectIds as a List<Guid>()
```

The following error is showing on debug

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'u => (Guid?)u == EntityShaperExpression: 
    DataApp.Entities.Project
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.Id' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Any` to `Contains`:

```cs
var projects = _projectRepo
     .FindAll(x => listProjectIds.Contains(x.Id))
     .ToList();
```